# Environmental variable with parentheses results in "unexpected token" error

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have a PowerShell (2.0) script that runs an executable beneath my program files directory, and I'm using an environmental variable to reference the path:

```
Start-Process "$($env:ProgramFiles)\ProgramFolder\Executable.exe"
```

This worked fine on my x86 machine, but now I'm trying to run it on an x64 machine.  Since the executable is 32-bit, it resides beneath "C:\Program Files (x86)", and therefore I've adjusted my script as follows since the environmental variable I need to use is `ProgramFiles(x86)`:

```
Start-Process "$($env:ProgramFiles(x86))\ProgramFolder\Executable.exe"
```

I'm getting this error though:

> Unexpected token '(' in expression or statement.

So how do I reference that environmental variable given that it contains parentheses?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the subexpression `$()` in this case:

```
"${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\ProgramFolder\Executable.exe"
```

Outputs:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\ProgramFolder\Executable.exe
```

If you still want to use a subexpression, you can specify a variable name that contains PowerShell syntax characters like so:

```
"$(${env:ProgramFiles(x86)})\ProgramFolder\Executable.exe"
```

Comment: Actually, Keith, you _must_ use the subexpression in this case: the value of `${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}` is `C:\Program Files (x86)` -- note the space before the left-paren! Your first code fragment is not accessing `${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}` but rather `${env:ProgramFiles}+"(x86)"` which does not include that ever-important space. :-)

Comment: Yup, didn't notice the missing space.  PowerShell stops "reading" the variable name when it sees that first paren.  And that is what the `{}` are for.  Updated the answer.  Thanks.